# Detecting Default constructor works or not

Tags: c++, constructor

I have a simple class definition in `Foo.h` like :

```
template <typename T>
class Foo
{
  public:
    Foo();
  private:
     char *topPtr;
}
```

I've implemented   Foo.cpp like :

```
template <typename T>
Foo<T>::Foo(){
    cout<<"default constructor is runned"<<endl;
    this.topPtr=NULL;
    if(topPtr==NULL){cout<<"topPtr is null"<<endl;}
}
```

Now, to see whether my Stack constructor is run or not, I write a simple main.cpp like :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Foo.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
    Foo<int> foo1();
    return 0;

}
```

I supposed to see *"default constructor is runned"* and *"topPtr is null"* messages on my terminal,however I've got nothing. Is there anyone to help me ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement `Foo<int> foo1();` declares a function foo1 which returns `Foo<int>`. You should be doing:
`Foo<int> foo1{};`

See this: [Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)

And your `this.topPtr=NULL;` should be `this->topPtr=NULL;`

Comment: when I do it Foo<int> foo1{}, it means that I create a Foo object with name foo1?? @NedStark

Comment: @MM. I think you're wrong. When I change it to foo1{} I got compile error

Comment: @caesar `Foo<int> foo1;` is legal as well for all C++ versions - the `{}` will only work in later 'modern' versions

Comment: @juanchopanza btw, I use c++98 not 11

Comment: @caesar then your compiler doesn't support universal initialization. Use `Foo<int> foo1;` (and you should have `topPtr` in an constructor initializer list ideally; though in this case it hardly matters, i.e. `Foo<T>::Foo() : topPtr(NULL) {...}`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `()`, by using it, you're declaring a function named `foo1` that returns `Foo<int>` and takes no parameter.

```
Foo<int> foo1; // It calls default constructor
```

To use `this` pointer you should use `->` not `.`

```
this->topPtr // to dereference this pointer
```